# even pesudo class not working tailwindcss reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

My end goal is to create a table with an even item with a different background color.

Form the official [docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/pseudo-class-variants/#even-child). I understood that we have to add the even class to the child called in the loop. I tried placing the class in all possible places and its still not working.

```
<table className="table-fixed shadow-lg">
    <thead className="py-2 bg-gray-200">
        ......
   </thead>
   <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td className="px-4 py-2 uppercase text-center font-bold">date</td>
          <td className="px-4 py-2 uppercase text-center font-bold w-100">event</td>
       </tr>
       {eventsData[this.state.currentYear].map(event =>(
           <tr className="even:bg-gray-300">
               <td className="px-4 py-2">{event.date}</td>
               <td className="px-4 py-2">{event.name}</td>
           </tr>
        ))}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

tailwind.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      spacing:{
        '128':'32rem',
      }
    },
  },
  variants: ['even'],
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Did you add the `even` class to your tailwind config?

Comment: @Redline I tired adding it, but it didn't work. have updated the question with the config

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

Your tailwind config file is wrong. You need to enable the `even` variant for the `backgroundColor` class. Update your config to look like this:

```
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  variants: {
    backgroundColor: ['even', ...],
  },
}
```

Comment: I tried the config in this way and still didn't work